# What is the correct way to override OnActivated in Xamarin Forms? Am getting unexpected results

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

The [Facebook SDK directs me](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) to use the OnActivated event to log certain events. (or to selectively not log them.)

It tells me to override the iOS OnActivated event. (see also [Xamarin docs.](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.OnActivated/))

When I type in "override OnActivated" the following code is generated

```
    [Export("applicationDidBecomeActive:")]
    public void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

this is in contrast to every other override, there is no export

```
    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
    }
```

Does this mean that Xamarin has a bug, or this is a different implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the correct way to override `OnActivated` for Xamarin.iOS.

The `Export` attribute will appear when you try to override `OnActivated` when your `AppDelegate` already has an existing `public override void OnActivated` method.

I have tested the below code in my Xamarin.iOS app and it triggers as expected when the app is activated.

## Code

```cs
public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    ...

    public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.OnActivated(uiApplication);

        //Do Stuff
    }

    ....
}
```